# SQLAlchemy Self Referencing Relationship - NoReferencedTableError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, self-reference

I'm using SA 0.6.6, Declarative style, against Postgres 8.3, to map Python objects to a database.  I have a table that is self referencing and I'm trying to make a relationship property for it's children.  No matter what I try, I end up with a NoReferencedTableError.

My code looks exactly like the [sample code from the SA website for how to do this very thing](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html?highlight=adjacency%20list#adjacency-list-relationships).

Here's the class.

```
class FilterFolder(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'FilterFolder'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    isShared = Column(Boolean,default=False)
    isGlobal = Column(Boolean,default=False)
    parentFolderId = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('FilterFolder.id'))
    childFolders = relationship("FilterFolder",
                    backref=backref('parentFolder', remote_side=id)
                    )
```

Here's the error I get:

NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key assocated with column 'FilterFolder.parentFolderId' could not find table 'FilterFolder' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a foolish mistake on my part.  I typically specify my FK's by specifying the Entity type, not the string.  I am using different schemas, so when defining the FK entity as a string I also need the schema.

Broken:

```
parentFolderId = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('FilterFolder.id'))
```

Fixed:

```
parentFolderId = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('SchemaName.FilterFolder.id'))
```

Comment: For getting back and answering your own question, our village will sacrifice a goat in your honor, Corey Coogan. Unfortunately it will not help me with my problem, but you have pleased our gods.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code with SQLAlchemy 0.6.6 and sqlite. I was able to create the tables, add a parent and child combination, and retrieve them again using a `session.query`.

As far as I can tell, the exception you mentioned (`NoReferencedTableError`) is thrown in `schema.py` (in the SQLAlchemy source) exclusively, and is not database specific.

Some questions: Do you see the same bug if you use an sqlite URL instead of the Postgres one? How are you creating your schema? Mine looks something like this:

```
engine = create_engine(db_url)
FilterFolder.metadata.create_all(self.dbengine)
```

Comment: We're not creating our schema with SA, but are doing it with Scripts. I will give sqlite a try and see what happens.